# Background service not running may be because of doze mode

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-workmanager

I want to upload some data on server exactly on 11:59 Pm. On this time I want to collect data and whenever Internet is available it should upload data. First choice is to use `WorkManager` But, I can't set it on exact time. For exact time we have to use `AlarmManager` and we have to implement our own logic or broadcastreciever for internet.

So, I am setting `OneTimeWorkRequest` for this using AlarmManager. But problem is it not working in background and working fine when app is in foreground.

**Manifest**

```
<service android:name=".Home.services.WorkerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

**Starting service from fragment**

```
 private void setUpService(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WorkerService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getForegroundService(getActivity(),0,intent,0);
    else pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(),0,intent,0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    assert alarmManager != null;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}
```

**WorkService**

```
public class WorkerService extends Service {

AppDatabase database;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this);

    readSteps();

    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

    int user_id = database.getUserDao().getSuperUser().id;
    Date date = new Date();
    String formattedDate = String.valueOf(DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd",date));

    float steps = database.getFitnessDao().getDateData(date,user_id).getSteps();
    Data data = new Data.Builder()
            .putInt("user_id",user_id)
            .putString("date",formattedDate)
            .putFloat("steps",steps)
            .build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(StepWorker.class)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .setInputData(data)
            .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);
}

private void readSteps(){
    Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .addOnSuccessListener(dataSet -> {
                int super_user = database.getUserDao().getSuperUser().id;
                float total = dataSet.isEmpty() ? 0 : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                database.getFitnessDao().updateSteps(super_user,total,new Date());
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            });
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your service class `WorkerService` to run it in background continuously i have edited your service class , use it

```
    public class WorkerService extends Service {

    AppDatabase database;

    @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this);

        readSteps();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
// check here the device current time is equal to 11:59 Pm or not 
// run your code if current current time is equal to 11:59
            handler.postDelayed(this, 30000);

    }
}, 30000); // every 30 seconds

       return START_STICKY;
    }


    private void readSteps(){
        Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                .readDailyTotal(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .addOnSuccessListener(dataSet -> {
                    int super_user = database.getUserDao().getSuperUser().id;
                    float total = dataSet.isEmpty() ? 0 : dataSet.getDataPoints().get(0).getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                    database.getFitnessDao().updateSteps(super_user,total,new Date());
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                });
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                startMyOwnForeground();
            } else {
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1");
                Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                        .build();
                startForeground(1, notification);
            }
        }
      @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private void startMyOwnForeground() {
            String channelName = "BackgroundService";
            NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel("2", channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            assert manager != null;
            manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "2");
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                    .build();
            startForeground(2, notification);
        }
      @Override
        public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
            Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
            restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());        
            PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmService.set(
                    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
                    restartServicePendingIntent);

            super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        }
    }
```

> Now start the service in fragment like this

```
startService(new Intent(context, WorkerService.class));
```

Comment: it will not drain too much battery if i check on every 30 seconds? It is not possible that i trigger foreground service on exact time using AlarmManager?

Comment: yes it will drain battery but what is the device is already in DOZE mode ? in that case the alarm manager might not work , so background service is needed to handle DOZE mode

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will let you choose an exact time, unless you get whitelisted from Doze.  Which must be done by the user, not the app.  Both Alarms and WorkManager are effected by it.  If the phone is off when the alarm or work is supposed to be done, it will wait for the next Doze window if the app isn't whitelisted.

Comment: So what should be the best solution to run this service? I am not sure it is not running because of doze mode only.

Comment: You should use the foreground service, as android apply the restriction on the bg services, other thing will be to go with work manager if you want to schedule a task or want to perform some operations. The system will look for approriate time including all the constraints doze mode etc. This will guarantee execution but time is not exact.

Comment: the best alternate is to run background and check the current time every 30 second when the time is equal to desired time , do your work if doze mode is creating problem for you